# Xcode 6.1 with Instruments 6.1 not working

Tags: xcode, instruments

I'm experienced a weird issue with Instruments. When I try to Profile the application, it gets stuck on an interface and becomes unresponsive. The same application is running perfectly on both Simulator and Device -- when not run with Instruments.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? What's the workaround?

**Additional Information:**

1). This situation is occurring with both Allocations and Energy Diagnostics templates.

2). I'm profiling using "Debug" Build Configuration.

3). This issue is reproducing for more than one application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there were some `NSLog` statements in the code, and Instruments immediately freezes when `NSLog` statement is called. Pretty annoying and inconvenient (if you ask me).

Removing ALL `NSLog` statements from the code fixed the problem.